# Hide all options in a select list except one with specific value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to hide of all option in select element except one with value `"all"`.

```
<select id="#list'>
 <option value="all">All</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 .....
</select>
```

How can I achieve this using jQuery?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us! Since your profile says Full Stack Developer, you must be able to come up with something yourself, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Your select box HTML is invalid as its missing `"` around it's `id`
2. use `value!=` to hide other options

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$('select option[value!=all]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="#list"><!-- correct quotes here-->
 <option value="all">All</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```